# Call variable outside of loop and if statement

Tags: php

Hello so I have some lines of code and what I'm trying to do is to echo out the variable in inside the loop. Here is the code:

```
if(!empty($output['txt_1'])) {
                $bind = array(
                    ":username" => $output['txt_1']
                );
                $accounts = $db->select("accounts", "username = :username", $bind);
                if(count($accounts) > 0) {
                    foreach ($accounts as $ac) {
                        $r_1 = $ac['sponsorID'];
                    }
                } else {
                    $sid = array(
                    ":sponsorID" => $randl1_1
                    );
                    $accounts = $db->select("accounts", "sponsorID = :sponsorID", $sid);

                    while(count($accounts) > 0) {
                        $r_1 = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
                    }
                }               
    }

echo $r_1;
```

Whenever I run the code, I get `Undefined variable: r_1`. I think it's because it's inside the loop, is there any chance to call out the variable outside the if statement and the loop? Thanks.

Comment: If `$output['txt_1']` is empty the loop never runs and the variable is not initialised, hence `undefined`

Comment: @HoboSapiens The $output['txt_1'] isn't empty..

Comment: The message you are getting implies that it is. Why don't you test it and see?

Comment: @HoboSapiens  
You are correct. The problem is that some of my input text are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$output['txt_1']` is considered empty and since that evaluates to true, your block inside the outer IF statement wont execute. therefore, the last `echo $r_1` line gives the undefined error.

Comment: How is it considered empty sir?

Comment: Well, if it hasn't been given a value, then the default value is NULL. NULL to me counts as empty value. If you did `$output['txt_1']='something';`  as your first statement, then your IF block will execute because you have then given a value.

Comment: You are correct. The problem is that some of my input text are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Define `r_1` outside the `if` statement, first.